# Storing web pages, including html, css, images, etc. in Mongodb

Tags: html, mongodb, ms-word, database

I am converting MS Word documents to HTML, which I am then going to display in an I-frame in an HTML5 canvas, along with other interactive elements.

Of course the converted document will be a web page with html, css, image, etc files all contributing to the final display.

I am storing all of my multi-media in this application in GridFS in Mongodb. It is being served up by a servlet.

Is there a good strategy or implementation I can use to store in mongodb, all of the files that go into making up the web page? I thought about saving the directory in a zip file in GridFS, but I don't want to unzip in order to serve up the content.

Comment: Does this help: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/gridfs/#gridfs-files-collection

Comment: Doesn't really help - I am currently using GridFS to store video, audio and image files, so I understand in general how to use it. The problem is that a web page is comprised of a lot of files, all referenced to each other (html, css, image). I want to store that in mongodb/GridFS, preferably as a self-referenced unit, and be able to  provide it to a caller using a servlet.

Comment: I don't understand the hold on this question - it is a problem that people have across many different technologies - how do you create a data version of a web page, which consists of many different files that internally reference each other. In other words, what is the alternative to a file-system-based representation of this data. Seems pretty important, clear, precise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that solution for this problem is pretty simple:

1. You need to make sure that all links in html/css/js are relative (you can convert them from absolute to relative when you save them in mongodb).
2. Your servlet should handle properly all requests, parse the request path, read requested resource and return it as a result.

For example. Let's assume that you have page `testA.html`, `testB.html`, `script.js` and `style.css`. You store all of them in MongoDB, so you should know the name of file and it's content. Let's take a look what you will need to handle:

1. user requests page `http://yourmongodb/testA.html` - your servlet parses this url, finds that it expects document testA.html, so you need to find this document in mongodb and return it's content.
2. Browser parses content of `testA.html` and finds `script.js` and `style.css`. If you keep everything as relative addresses, so browser will do two additional requests: `http://yourmongodb/script.js` and `http://yourmongodb/style.css`, which again tells you what you need to find in mongodb and what you need to return.
3. If `testA.html` has link to `testB.html` (and link is relative) - when user will click on link - browser will request `http://yourmongodb/testB.html`.

If you also want to support directories you can keep this information as a additional peace in files collection.

Comment: Thanks, this is an obvious answer that I missed since I don't use paths. Path is optional in GridFS, and file id is the fastest way to get a file. I retrieve all my files by id.

I can use path, however, to access these files. The first part activates the servlet, and the 2nd part will find the file in Mongodb. As you say, I can keep relative paths consistent, which works in both the web page and Mongo.

I'll need to create a method to upload a directory structure in the mongo GridFS DAO. It isn't a trivial, but it will work. If no one suggests anything simpler, I'll do this.

Thanks